# I can't get to work the bootstrap.min.css in printThis.js

Tags: php, laravel

I hope someone can help me with this. I am using `printThis.js` to print a document. I have `bootstrap.min.css` located in the public folder. The thing is, I couldn't get it to work. I already tried possible answers but not working.

Here's my code at "`barcode.blade.php`". What I wanted is to make this.

`loadCSS: "{{ asset('Admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"`

work. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('Admin/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('Admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
  <style>
    .row{
      margin: 50px;
    } 
    p{
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

  </style>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         @foreach($barcodes as $barcode)
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($barcode->pxbarcode, 'C128A')}}"  />
                 <p>{{$barcode->pxbarcode}}</p>      
             </div>
         @endforeach
     </div>           
  </div>

  <div class="w3-right footer">
    <button id="print" class="w3-button w3-blue">Print</button>
    <a href="{{url('admin/home')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
  </div>

  <script src="{{ asset('Admin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/printThis.js')}}"></script>

  <script>
    $('#print').click(function(){
      $('.container').printThis({
          debug: false,               // show the iframe for debugging
          importCSS: true,            // import parent page css
          importStyle: false,         // import style tags
          printContainer: true,       // print outer container/$.selector
          loadCSS: "{{ asset('Admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}",                // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
          pageTitle: "",              // add title to print page
          removeInline: false,        // remove inline styles from print elements
          removeInlineSelector: "*",  // custom selectors to filter inline styles. removeInline must be true
          printDelay: 333,            // variable print delay
          header: "<h2>Print Barcode</h2>",               // prefix to html
          footer: null,               // postfix to html
          base: false,                // preserve the BASE tag or accept a string for the URL
          formValues: true,           // preserve input/form values
          canvas: false,              // copy canvas content
          doctypeString: '<!DOCTYPE html>', // enter a different doctype for older markup
          removeScripts: false,       // remove script tags from print content
          copyTagClasses: false,      // copy classes from the html & body tag
          beforePrintEvent: null,     // callback function for printEvent in iframe
          beforePrint: null,          // function called before iframe is filled
          afterPrint: null            // function called before iframe is removed
      });
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is how it looks when i click the print button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebkMj.png)

As you can see, I'm using a bootstrap in my blade and it is not taking effect when I print it.

Comment: If you hit F12 in Chrome and bring up the dev tools console are there any error messages?

Comment: no, there were no errors.

Comment: i think bootstrap only works for styles of html classes. and your print script is only printing .continer and theres no bootstrap classes in there.  or am i wrong? bootstrap is only appllied as default for <h2> div in header.

Comment: Turn on the `debug: true,` option and check the iframe it makes. Maybe there's an error lurking there. Also, I don't think you have to use `loadCSS` if `importCSS` is true.

Comment: @j.albertoureña you mean i just need to write my own css styles in the blade to get desired result?

Comment: @ourmandave i set the debug to true, still, no errors found. can you guide me on how can I importCSS?

Comment: just curious, why do you want to load css inside jquery block?didnt it load already in the link <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('Admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

Comment: @afikri yes it's already loaded in the blade. but not in the print page. here, look at this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebkMj.png, what I wanted is, how it looks in my blade will be also the output in the print page. It's printing vertically, not horizontally, I hope you get my point

Comment: Ah, i got your point, so the problem is that you want to load your css correctly inside the jquery block, right?

Comment: @afikri yah you got it. Do you know how to do this ? here, i just followed this tutorial in youtube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z18308OiBs&t=27s, look how he just paste his code in loadCSS at 2:52

Comment: i dont really see the problem. i see the result as expected. reorder the code and align the divs. you will see youre only printing the cointainer .. no more rendering is printed no buttons printed.. what is what you expect as reult? if you preffer i can edit your codes question.

Comment: @j.albertoureña here,  i.stack.imgur.com/ebkMj.png, if I have lots of data, like that barcodes, say I have 20 barcodes to print, the output that you will see in the print output are arranged vertically, they don't occupy the whole page, say in the first page, what i wanted is to set it up horizontally in the print output so as to occupy the whole paper. I hope you get my point. or can you show me the image of what you rendered in print ?

Comment: It's strange, as it says here https://github.com/jasonday/printThis, in the loadCSS, it says provide a URL for an additional stylesheet to the printThis iframe. Empty string (off) by default. Logically, it should work because url you provide is correct.

Comment: @afikri yah, and i really don't know how to do it.

Comment: hi, can you try loadCss:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" just to see if it works

Comment: @afikri I tried your suggestion but ,the print output is still like the image I showed in my question.

Comment: i mean print scripts is only printing container div. and the styles are correct, if you want to print the whole page try using `block` instead `row` and `col-md-12` instead `col-md-4` in the div classes.

Answer (score 0):

just import your bootstrap like that

```
<link href="URL to bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media='all'/>
```

and call printThis like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/printThis.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    $("#printBtn").click(function () {
        j('#divToPrint').printThis({
            importCSS: true,
            loadCSS: true,
            canvas: true
        });
    })
</script>
```

It worked perfectly for me ... (btw : I'am using symfony 4 with twig as Template engine)

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
    loadCSS: "css/bootstrap.min.css"
}
$('#printButton').on('click', function () {
    $('.container').printThis(options);
});
```

OR

```
$('#printButton').on('click', function () {
    $('.container').printThis({
        loadCSS: "css/bootstrap.min.css"
    });
});
```

Comment: Please use a few sentences to explain the solution not only post bare code.